# Pass multiple variables into ggtitle R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have made some variables that I would like to pass into `ggtitle`. Here are the variables I made

```
ip_case_index <- paste("IP Only Case Index =",
                       round(mean(mdc5ip$case_index), digits = 2)
)
oa_case_index <- paste("OA Case Index",round(mean(edata$Std_Pmt_All_Clm / 
                                 edata$Pred_Amt_Renormal),
                            digits = 2)
)
sn_case_index <- paste("IP and SNF Only"
                       ,round(mean(mdc5sn$case_index), digits = 2)
)
```

I want to do something like

```
ggtitle(ip_case_index, oa_case_index, sn_case_index)
```

Which of course does not return the desired title format. How I would like it to show in the title is this

```
ip_case_index
oa_case_index
sn_case_index
```

Where each variable is on it's own line of the title. I tried using `\n` to add a new line to no avail, I tried using `atop` which made each successive line smaller thus hard to see as it is treating each variable as a subtitle so Title Subtitle subtitle.

I have also tried using multiple `paste()` arguments inside of `ggtitle` by using `c(paste(), paste(), paste())`, which returns the first variable.

I have also tried the following:

```
plot.title = c(ip_case_index, oa_case_index, sn_case_index)
ggtitle(plot.title)
```

which also only give the first one.

So I am a bit confused on how to proceed from here.

Any help is much appreciated.
Thank you,

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I created some fake data to make the code work, but you can of course adapt it for your real data.

```
dat=data.frame(x=rnorm(10), y=rnorm(10))

ip_case_index <- paste("IP Only Case Index =",
                       round(mean(rnorm(10)), digits = 2))
oa_case_index <- paste("OA Case Index",round(mean(rnorm(10)),
                                             digits = 2))
sn_case_index <- paste("IP and SNF Only"
                       ,round(mean(rnorm(10)), digits = 2))

ggplot(dat, aes(x,y)) + geom_point() + 
  ggtitle(paste0(ip_case_index,"\n", oa_case_index, "\n", sn_case_index))
```

[image]

Comment: oh so I was actually close using the \n just some formatting issues, thank you for your help!

Comment: Yes. The general idea is to create the title string using `paste` or `paste0` then just provide that as the argument to `ggtitle`.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:
library(glue)
+

```
labs (title = glue("IP and SNF Only ="
                       , round(mean(rnorm(10)), digits = 2)),
          subtitle = glue("OA Case Index =", round(mean(rnorm(10)),
                                                 digits = 2),
                          "\nIP and SNF Only =", round(mean(rnorm(10)), digits = 2)),
caption = "Some text")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more direct approach using paste() to concat test strings and variables.
 ggtitle(paste("Countries Ranked by % Share of Total Deaths ", latestDAy), subtitle = paste("Duration = ", totalDays, " Days"))